# Quadratic constraints in JuMP

Tags: optimization, constraint, julia, jump

I am a bit new to programming and am currently working with solving optimization problems in JuMP in Julia.

I got a tip from the JuMP page that I should also use `@constraint` if a term is quadratic. However, how do I know if a constraint is quadratic?

For instance, should I use `@constraint` or `@NLconstraint` for $z - 2 + 4 z y = 0$ and $x - z^2 \geq 0$?

All I know is that it should have the form $\frac{1}2 x H  x + q  x$ where $x$ is the vector with all the variables.

Comment: `1/2 x * H * x` is just a fancy way to write $\sum_{j_1} \sum_{j_2} h_{j_1,j_2} x_{j_1} x_{j_2}$

Comment: If you're looking for solvers, note that quadratic constraints mean that your model is not a quadratic programming problem. You need a QPQC solver, or nonlinear programming solver

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A "quadratic constraint" is a constraint of the form $f(x) \leq 0$, where $f(x)$ is a quadratic function, i.e., as you wrote,
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^{T}Hx + q^{T}x + b
$$
for some square matrix $H \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, vector $q \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, and some scalar $b \in \mathbb{R}$.

In JuMP, you can declare such quadratic constraints with the `@constraint` syntax directly. The `@NLconstraint` macro is designed for more general nonlinear that require special handling of function evaluation and derivatives. For instance, if your constraints have high-order polynomial functions ($x^{3}$ and above), or terms like `sin`, `cos`, `log` or `exp`, you should use `@NLconstraint`.

You can have a look at the [quadratic portfolio optimization](https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/stable/tutorials/nonlinear/portfolio/) and [quadratically constrained programming](https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/stable/tutorials/nonlinear/qcp/) examples from the JuMP documentation.

PS: there is more JuMP-centric traffic on the [Julia Discourse](https://discourse.julialang.org/c/domain/opt/13) forum. You are more likely to get expert feedback there, especially on code-related questions.

Comment: You can build higher order polynomials via quadratic constraints though or use `PolyJuMP` compared  to the general purpose `@NLConstraints`. This can be useful to make some solvers like Gurobi solve problems they won't otherwise as  `@NLConstraints` is not supported by some, however quadratic terms are.